# java sql exception parameter not set

Tags: java, jdbc, parameters, sqlexception, ucanaccess

I am trying to get data from a database in a table with 2 where parameters,
When i try to execute this code it gives the error: Parameter not set.
I think it is a small mistake but I can't find it.
The problem could be with the 2 where parameters, i never used 2 before. Can anyone help me?

```
public static void tabelVullen(int Kaartnummer,int Datum){
Connection con;
    try {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(DB, "", "");
        PreparedStatement s = con.prepareStatement("Select Kaartnummer, Datum, Maaltijd, Prijs FROM Logbestanden WHERE Kaartnummer=? AND Datum=?");
        s.setInt(1, Kaartnummer);
        rset = s.executeQuery();

        while(rset.next()){
        String[] Logboek = new String[4];
        Logboek[0]=rset.getString("Kaartnummer");
        Logboek[1]=rset.getString("Datum");
        Logboek[2]=rset.getString("Maaltijd");
        Logboek[3]=rset.getString("Prijs");
        model.addRow(Logboek);

        }


        s.close();
        con.close();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Error LogbestandenWeergeven: " + e);

    }
}
```

This is the error

```
Error LogbestandenWeergeven: net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: Parameter not set
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to supply a second parameter for the Datum value:

```java
PreparedStatement s = con.prepareStatement("Select Kaartnummer, Datum, Maaltijd, Prijs FROM Logbestanden WHERE Kaartnummer=? AND Datum=?");
s.setInt(1, Kaartnummer);
s.setInt(2, Datum);  // this is what you are missing
rset = s.executeQuery();
```